# Convert byte array to collection of enums in C#

Tags: c#, casting, endianness

I have a byte array that recevies enums in little endianess byte order from a function `GetData()` and I want to convert the array into a collection of enums.
How would I copy and cast the bytes in LE order to the enum values in C#? I have a C++ background and not too familiar with the language.
This is a sample code snippet:

```
public enum BarID
{
  TAG0 = 0x0B01,
  TAG1 = 0x0B02,
}

public class TestClass
{
  List<BarID> ids;
  internal TestClass() 
  {
      ids = new List<BarID>();
      byte[] foo = GetData(); // returns  01 0b 00 00 02 0b 00 00
      // cast byte array so that ids contains the enums 'TAG0' and 'TAG1'      

  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary`? You can store KeyValuePairs togetter. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: In a loop, `(BarID)BitConverter.ToInt32(foo, [pos]);`, where `[pos] = 0, 4, ...`

Comment: @Jimi Would this change somehow if I was on a 32bit System? Would the enums be of a different size?

Comment: No, it's the same size. But, see what Marc Gravell wrote.

Comment: @tzippy what you *do* need to be careful about, however, is CPU endianness; some approaches that *appear* to work - only work by accident of the CPU on the current machine

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks Marc! Is there a way in .NET to get the CPUs endianess?

Comment: `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Marc's answer is both good and fast, that works only on .NET Core, or if you use additional nugets. If that could be a problem (or you target older Framework versions) you can use a solution like this:

```cs
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00 };

return BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
    ? ConvertLittleEndian(bytes)
    : ConvertBigEndian(bytes);
```

Where the conversion methods:

```cs
private static unsafe BarID[] ConvertLittleEndian(byte[] bytes)
{
    var barIds = new BarID[bytes.Length / 4];
    fixed (byte* pBytes = bytes)
    {
        BarID* asIds = (BarID*)pBytes;
        for (int i = 0; i < barIds.Length; i++)
            barIds[i] = asIds[i];
    }

    return barIds;
}
```

If you know that your code will be used on little endian CPUs (eg. it is meant to be a Windows app), then you don't even need the big endian version:

```cs
private static BarID[] ConvertBigEndian(byte[] bytes)
{
    var barIds = new BarID[bytes.Length / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < barIds.Length; i++)
    {
        int offset = i * 4;
        barIds[i] = (BarID)((bytes[offset] << 3) | (bytes[offset + 1] << 2)
            | (bytes[offset + 2] << 1) | bytes[offset + 3]);
    }

    return barIds;
}
```

Comment: "Though Marc's answer is both good and fast, that works only on .NET Core." - this is entirely incorrect; it works just about everywhere, including .NET Framework down to 4.5: - you just need a package reference to System.Memory: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/

Comment: Answer corrected. Maybe it's just my fault that I prefer not to add many 3rd party dependencies to my libraries so they support Span and its friends only starting with .NET Core 3/Standard 2.1

Answer (score 2):

The interesting step here is reading the bytes *reliably* in a little-endian way (where "reliable" here means "works on any CPU, not just one that happens to be little-endian itself"); fortunately, `BinaryPrimitives` makes this obvious, giving you an `int` from a `Span<byte>` (the `byte[]` from `GetData()` is implicitly castable to `Span<byte>`). Then from the `int` you can just cast to `BarID`:

```cs
Span<byte> foo = GetData();
var result = new BarID[foo.Length / 4];
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = (BarID)BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(foo.Slice(4 * i));
}
```

The `Slice` step here just offsets where we should start reading in the span.

Comment: This is much effective than Tomas' answer, though it works only on .NET Core (or .NET Standard 2.1).

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg no, that's incorrect; it works everywhere down to .NET 4.5 / .NET Standard 1.1 / various others - you just need [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/)

Comment: Ah, you are right after all, I meant without allowing nuget packages.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg well, yeah, but since that's the de-facto distribution mechanism in .NET, disallowing nuget packages is very much: doing things the daft way :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var foo = new byte[] {0x01, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00}.ToList();
IEnumerable<byte> bytes;
var result = new List<BarID>();

while ((bytes = foo.Take(4)).Any())
{
    var number = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
        ? BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.ToArray(), 0)
        : BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);


    var enumValue = (BarID) number;

    result.Add(enumValue);

    foo = foo.Skip(4).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is not reliable - it is CPU-endian; it also allocates like anything

Comment: and now it allocates *even more* (on big-endian architectures, at least) :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if the array values are grouped by two or four, however the pattern is basically the same:

```
public enum BarID
{
    TAG0 = 0x0B01,
    TAG1 = 0x0B02,
}

public class TestClass
{
    List<BarID> ids;
    internal TestClass()
    {
        ids = new List<BarID>();
        byte[] foo = GetData(); // returns  01 0b 00 00 02 0b 00 00
                                // cast byte array so that ids contains the enums 'TAG0' and 'TAG1'      

        //create a hash-set with all the enum-valid values
        var set = new HashSet<int>(
            Enum.GetValues(typeof(BarID)).OfType<int>()
            );

        //scan the array by 2-bytes
        for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i += 2)
        {
            int value = foo[i] + foo[i + 1] << 8;
            if (set.Contains(value))
            {
                ids.Add((BarID)value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The set is not mandatory, but it should prevent invalid values to be casted to a tag. For instance, if the values are word-based, the `00 00` value is invalid.

As final consideration, I wouldn't do similar tasks in a class constructor: better to create the instance, then call a dedicated method to the conversion.